# Invalid json has suddenly started throwing parse errors

Tags: jquery, json, parse-error

There are two places where I have observed this. Both are AJAX calls which return some JSON which is used to populate the options of two select dropdowns. I am currently working on applying enhancements to these dropdowns using jquery's chosen plugin and I guess some change is causing this problem. I am not sure what exactly, because I reverted the changes for that module where I am getting the parse error, but the error is still happening.

So, I am asking, in general what could be the reasons behind invalid JSON suddenly causing problem. Please note that the returned JSON has always been invalid. I have made no changes to this. Also, I did not make any changes to the $.ajax calls. Sample of the JSON -

```
{
 "result":"success",
"reqparams": 
{"site_id": {"name":"site_id","display_name":"","possible_values":"","default_value":"","editable":"1","description":"the ad slot id provided by your 4th Screen account manager",},},
"optparams": {
"keywords": {"name":"keywords","display_name":"","possible_values":"","default_value":"","editable":"1","description":"",},
"reachability": {"name":"reachability","display_name":"","possible_values":"wifi[ADMARVEL_SEP]cell","default_value":"","editable":"1","description":"Information about how the device is being connected to the internet.",},
},
}
```

Note: the extra commas, e.g. after "description" attribute's value.

**Updates**
Code which generates JSON - sample code - please ignore the fact that json_encode is not being used. it is very old code.

```
if (is_array($reqd_params) && count($reqd_params) > 0)
        {
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            echo '{
                    "result":"success",
                    "reqparams": {';
            foreach ($reqd_params as $paramKey => $paramValArr)
            {
                echo '"'.$paramValArr['name'].'": {';
                echo '"name":"'.$paramValArr['name'].'",';
                echo '"display_name":"'.$paramValArr['display_name'].'",';
                echo '"possible_values":"'.$paramValArr['possible_values'].'",';
                echo '"default_value":"'.$paramValArr['default_value'].'",';
                echo '"editable":"'.$paramValArr['editable'].'",';
                echo '"description":"'.addslashes($paramValArr['description']).'",';
                echo '},';
            }
            echo '}';

            if(!empty($reportData) && $reportData != -1)
            {
                echo',';
                echo '"reportData":"'.htmlspecialchars($reportData).'"';
            }

            echo ' }';

        }
```

Client side  code

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: posturl,
            data : data,
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function(msg){

                         //not coming here
                        },

                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert("error "+errorThrown);

                                //alerts parse error
            }
                });
```

Comment: Can you please post the code which is generating this JSON. The problem is simply that it is adding a trailing comma to every line. The algorithm just needs to be changed to detect the last property of each object.

Comment: Let your code return valid JSON. The experience that it *used to work* is no excuse for deliberately serving incorrect JSON.

Comment: @Rob W I agree with you, but I am worried that something I changed might break all the existing places where invalid JSON is returned. I may miss out fixing all the places.

Comment: I assume that something like updating jquery could have caused this.

Comment: Are you saying that this invalid JSON is actually working on your site?

Comment: yes I upgraded from jquery 1.3.2 to 1.6.4.

Comment: yes invalid json was working earlier. with jquery 1.3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that this fact

```
I upgraded from jquery 1.3.2 to 1.6.4.
```

(from the comments)

and the fact that your jquery code used to accept incorrect JSON (as in: it was doing something "wrong") but now works as expected, are the source of the seen behaviour, as your question was.

As a sollution, in the case changing the code REALLY isn't an option, you could just change the datatype for the expected result, and go manually parse your `specialJSON` code.

Comment: wow great answer! Is there no other way to allow invalid json for now?A simple change in one place?

Comment: You can try using a different (text?) datatype, and then parse the string with `$.parseJSON`. I'm not sure why that might work, but a comment on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ implies that the parser from `.ajax` is more strict. There's obviously a big chance your situation is different, it it still throws an error. You might be stuck with writing a funciton specifically for your data to make valid JSON from your own version of JSON, and then call `$.parseJSON` on it?

Comment: I did the same thing, change datatype to "text" and did msg = $.parseJSON(msg);  and everything worked. This is fine, but I am asking if there is some other way so as to cut this step of doing this in every place where invalid JSON is returned. I wonder why jquery was allowing accepting invalid JSON earlier but not in this version. So, is it possible they have kept an option to allow invalid JSON? By the way thanks again for this much help. A +1 for you.

Comment: I assume it was a bug, and the bug now fixed. YOur code relied on the bug being there, so it is expected that this will be hard to stop. One thing would be to go back to the previous jquery version. Another would be to fix your function, but as you told, this would be scary. I'm sorry, I don't know any quicker methods ;)